# Send a function along with the scheme from backend in Alpacajs

Tags: alpacajs

I am having an API in backend to return the full json (schema and options) for a AlpacaJS form. The content-type of the response is `application/json`. Following is a sample response,

```
{
  "options": {
    "fields": {
      "students": {
        "items": {
          "type": "tablerow"
        },
        "type": "table"
      }
    },
    "form": {
      "buttons": {
        "submit": {
          "click": "function(){alert(\"sample\");}"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "schema": {
    "properties": {
      "students": {
        "items": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "required": true,
              "title": "Name",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "contact-number": {
              "title": "Age",
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "type": "object"
        },
        "type": "array"
      }
    },
    "type": "object"
  }
}
```

When I click on the `Submit` button, I get the following error in browser console,

`Uncaught TypeError: t.call is not a function`

I think the issue is that the function is considered as a string in the following section of the response.

```
"form": {
  "buttons": {
    "submit": {
      "click": "function(){alert(\"sample\");}"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way in AlpacaJS to send a javascript function from backend, or is there a way to convert the function string to a javascript function in frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get that, you should transform the *stringified* function to a function by doing `new Function('return ' + val)();` (beware this is a form of eval and [eval is evil](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)).

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/L5kmoueL/) for that.
Tell me if it didn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks @vert3x, I wrote a similar code which extracts the function parameters and function body, then fed them into `new Function(params)`, this works for me. I hope the solution you have suggested should also work. In my case the function to execute above logic is passes to `JSON.parse` as `JSON.parse(data, function(key, value)`.

Comment: Did you tested it?